# Staying at cousin's home in London, what documentation should I submit with my visa application?

Tags: uk, paperwork, london, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-accommodation

I am planning to stay at my cosuin's place in London, they are not sponsoring my trip we just will be staying with them for period of 10 days. 
What all documents are required by them apart from Invitation letter, electricity bill and office visiting card?

I mean to say, what documents from my cousin are required by me with invitation letter that I need to submit to obtain visitor's visa?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents

Comment: @AE, that's the answer to this, and many other similar questions. I suggest wrapping some verbiage around it and posting it as a canonical answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit your cousin's residency proof in London (indefinite or eu passport). If she is the owner, then property ownership and if she has rented, then rental agreement. Also, if a renter, permission from the property owner/management company that you have permission to stay. Utility bills under her or his name. Letter from her preferably undertaking that she will provide you a place during your stay there.

Apart from this, if your cousin is sponsoring you also you need to submit his/her proof of employment and bank statements.

Comment: I have successfully sponsored a visitor visa application three times. On each occasion the only documents I provided were a copy of my British passport, a covering letter confirming the accommodation arrangements, and my bank statements and salary slips. I did *not* send evidence of property ownership, while utility bills are explicitly stated as *not to be used as evidence* in the guidance https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: @Traveller the situation could be different depending on whether one is sponsoring the visit (as in your case) or just hosting the visitor (as in OP’s case), couldn’t it?

Comment: @jcaron Not dramatically, no IMHO. The rental approval is probably helpful if the accommodation provider isn’t a home owner. UKVI will ignore anything irrelevant and obliging them to wade through pages of extraneous documents isn’t a good idea, especially if those documents are specifically included in the list of what *not* to use. More isn’t always better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact case. I was visiting London and was staying with my cousin. I submitted the following documents from my cousin.

1. Invitation letter confirming that they are happy to accommodate me with address and phone number, which includes your name(s) and passport numbers.
2. Copy of his passport
3. His PR card (Visa, work permit, or anything equivalent is ok.)
4. He gave me a property tax bill in his name to prove that it is indeed his home.

That's all. No bank statements and all, as it is not relevant. He is not sponsoring me, just providing accommodation. My bank account had more than enough for the trip, along with a stable job.