# Accomodation for UK Visit Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, accommodation, invitation-letters

I will be visiting my friend in Glasgow come August. I will be staying with her in residence in Glasgow until the 28th after which we will move out and spend a couple of days in Brighton and some other places until the 2nd of September. Obviously we'll be looking to book Air BnBs for our trip and I plan to show the full itinerary during my visa interview. After the 2nd, I plan to stay with my mother's relatives in London for 3 days and fly out of the city. Question is, will I require an invitation letter, plus documents showing my mother's uncle is a national? I already have an invitation letter from my friend showing I'll be staying with her. Will I need to ask them to provide the same for the 2 days I'll be staying? My issue here is that they're old, and I don't want to bother them asking for their formal documents showing they own a place in London. Or is it better to modify my itinerary to show that I won't be staying with them, and instead show a dummy booking for a hotel.

Will it not look dubious though if I hand in an invitation letter from my friend, showing that I have accommodation for the first few days and then there's no proof for the rest of my trip? I'm assuming a detailed itinerary will be sufficient?

Comment: You’ll have to declare you have family in the UK in your application, so it makes sense to also be transparent about your intentions to stay with them. This answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68661/staying-at-cousins-home-in-london-what-documentation-should-i-submit-with-my-v indicates proof of their property ownership should be provided (along with residency proof and an invitation), however if they’re not sponsoring you financially and given that your intended stay with them is so short, it’s possible your application would succeed without it if all other aspects are strong.

Comment: s4 of the Supporting Documents Guide https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf specifically states that proof of hotel bookings is not required

Answer (score 1):

As part of your UK Visitor visa application, you are expected to provide a premise for wishing to enter the country. If that is to stay with your friend in Glasgow, a bit tourism, and a short stay with relatives, all perfectly reasonable, then provide all of those details.

The application has specific, separate questions about friends or family in the UK, their immigration status, and whether you intend to visit them. You don’t have to give an itinerary but you are expected to outline your plans.

For those with whom you will stay, you need to demonstrate that they are are able to host a guest for a given period (under the law, whether it be through home ownership, tenancy agreement, council permission).

You should offer any and all information, rather than risk a refusal for incomplete, insufficient, misunderstood, or illogical responses. Entry Clearance Officer are well experienced in spotting inconsistencies and evasions.